# How to search multiple columns in Google Spreadsheet and return values in other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have two spreadsheets and would like to enter a value into cell A1, have it check multiple columns in a spreadsheet named 'data' and output information from other columns if it's a match.

```
----------------------------------------------
|  J. Smith  |   1    |     2     |   ABC    |
----------------------------------------------
|  A. Smith  |   2    |     3     |   DEF    |
----------------------------------------------
```

I was able to write the following to check only one column but can't seem to get an 'or' statement to work:

```
=query(data!A:B;"select A,D where B ="&A1;1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your formula works at all, so I'm rather guessing what is required but would suggest you label your data source and in say D1 enter:

```
=query(data!A:D;"select A,B,C,D where B ="&$A1;1)
```

Output example with A1 = `2`:

[image: WA54928 example]