# Query or Filter formula to 'search for' and 'return' multiple words

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, regex

I am a basic user of Google Sheets and need help creating a new formula. I am trying to filter a worksheet so that it returns particular information into another sheet.
The filter I have created is working but not exactly how I want it! The column I am referring to has words such as:

- Solar
- Energy
- Battery

and sometimes may have two words in the cell such as:

- ENERGY COMPARISON, SOLAR (see image below)
  and these words are separated by a comma `,`

The formula I created recognizes the single words. However it does not bring over the words that belong to a cell with multiple words.

The example formula I am using that works is this:

```
=filter('Form responses'!A:A,'Form responses'!I:I="Solar")
```

How do I update it to also capture the multiple words?

[image]

[image]

Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi Leanne, welcome to SE! I'm sure we can help you, but unfortunately your question isn't sufficiently clear to me to help. Would you be able to a) mention the formula/filter you've tried so far, b) potentially share copy of the sheet you're working on with any irrelevant and sensitive data removed or c) add example input output like for example in this well-written question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54928/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-google-spreadsheet-and-return-values-in-other?rq=1
Lastly, please explain "I am not va basic user" and "word/filter".

Comment: @Leanne You are looking for `=regexmatch` with a regex like this one `SOLAR|SOLAR & ENERGY` where `|` means `OR`. You can update your question with more details/data as @cornelius suggest

Comment: Thanks all.  The formula I have used is this:

Comment: I cannot provide a copy of the sheet as i am not the owner and due to privacy but if this is not clear then I can create a new one showing what I have done :)  Thank you so much for responding all

Comment: Thanks all.  The formula I have used is this:  =filter('Form responses'!A:A,'Form responses'!I:I="Solar").... and this is working but what I also want it to do is to also filter into the sheet anything with the words Solar & Energy in column I, and not just the words SOLAR as sometimes customers can select more than one option and I want to be able to show this on the sheet I am working with... this sheet pulls from a main data source that has lots of options (such as solar - energy - led - etc.)

Comment: I suppose I need to know how to extend the formula to also capture solar and energy... for example would I just add the words OR to the middle to have it look like this:   =filter('Form responses'!A:A,'Form responses'!I:I="Solar"or=filter('Form responses'!A:A,'Form responses'!I:I="Solar & Energy").

Comment: Hi Leanne, please use the [edit] button to move that information into the body of your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the [OP's Edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/134988/4) things are quite clearer.

---

#### Using the FILTER function

```
=FILTER('Form responses'!A:A, REGEXMATCH('Form responses'!I:I, "Solar"))
```

***Extra tip***
If you were to use the `|` (pipe symbol) in the FILTER function which stands for `OR`, then the formula would change to:

```
=FILTER('Form responses'!A:A, REGEXMATCH('Form responses'!I:I, "Solar|Energy Comparison"))
```

But you don't really need to because the first condition (`Solar`) **already includes** all text that has the word `Solar`.

---

#### Using a QUERY

```
=QUERY('Form responses'!A:I, "select A where I matches '.\bSolar\b.' ",0)
```

As before, it is **not necessary** to use the `|` (pipe)

```
=QUERY('Form responses'!A:I, "select A where I matches '.\bSolar\b.|.\bEnergy\b.' ",0)
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try and find out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that: **results given by the following provided formula are highly dependent on the way you have built your form**.

If for any reason it does not work for you, please -as mentioned by others- **share a link to a test spreadsheet with dummy data** (John for Mark, Mr Green for Mr Brown)*.

---

The query formula using a case-insensitive regular expression (regex) for your search will give the results you want.

```
=QUERY('Form responses'!A2:C200, ""select * where lower(A) matches 
       '.\bsolar\b.|.\benergy\b.'")
```

**Brief explanation** (of what the query "says")

*We assume your data starts at column `A`, row `2`, in the spreadsheet `Form responses` (`'Form responses'!A2:C200`)*

Choose the range `A2:C200` and return all the columns wherever -in your search within column `A`- you find results matching the case-insensitive words `solar` or `SOLAR` or even `sOlaR` or `energy` or `Energy` etc, no-matter how many or what characters are before or after them.

- **`*`**: everything (all columns in the range)
- **`lower(A)`**: make characters case-insensitive
- **`.*`**: **`.`** any character, **`*`** any number of times
- **`\b`**: word boundaries (prevents from matching `subsolar` or `solarized`)
- **`|`**: *(pipe)* **or**